# LinkedList iterator implementation for a wrapper class

Tags: java, iterator, wrapper

So I implemented the following LinkedList wrapper class:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class LinkedListWrapper {

    private LinkedList<String> listWrapper;

    public LinkedListWrapper(){
        this.listWrapper = new LinkedList<String>();
    }

    /**
     * Method to check if the linked list contains the string object.
     * @param str String object to check if the list contains.
     * @return True if the list contains it and false otherwise.
     */

    public boolean contains(String str){
        return this.listWrapper.contains(str);
    }

    /**
     * Method to add a String object to the list.
     * @param str String object to add.
     * @return True if the item was added and false otherwise.
     */

    public boolean add(String str){
        if(!this.contains(str)){
            this.listWrapper.add(str);
        }
        return false;
    }


    /**
     * Method to delete str object
     * @param str String object to delete
     * @return True if str was deleted and false otherwise.
     */

    public boolean delete(String str){
        return this.listWrapper.remove(str);
    }

}
```

However, Now that I create an array of LinkedListWrapper and I want to iterate through the linked list's strings, I obviously can't -  because I haven't implemented an iterator. I searched the [LinkedList API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) But I didn't quite get how to implement the Iterator properly.

Comment: Just implement `Iterable` and implement the `iterator` method in a way that's similar to how you implement `contains`. Note that you *probably* don't need to implement your own `Iterator` (or wrapper), unless you have additional requirements that you haven't told us about yet.

Comment: _Side note:_ Your `add` method always returns `false` even if the element was added.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, Thats excactly what I tried to do, that's why im here seeking help :(

Comment: @Slaw Thanks alot man! didn't notice it.

Comment: @will25g: I don't see that in your code however, what have you tried? More generally: what are you trying to achieve with this wrapper?

Comment: @JoachimSauer I was instructed to not create an Array of LinkedLists, but create a wrapper class like this and use delegation.

Comment: @will25g: I don't understand. How is this an alternative to an "Array of LinkedLists"? You only use one LinkedList ...

Comment: I create An array of these objects later on.. and I want to iterate through their string entries.

Comment: I still fail to see the benefit of having this wrapper over using a `LinkedList` directly, but it seems that whoever gave you that instruction also didn't do a good job of explaining *why* they want that ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the Interable<> interface and override its methods :

```
    class LinkedListWrappe implements Iterable<> { 

    // code for data structure 
    public Iterator<> iterator() { 
        return new CustomIterator<>(this); 
    } 
} 
class CustomIterator<> implements Iterator<> { 

    // constructor 
    CustomIterator<>(CustomDataStructure obj) { 
        // initialize cursor 
    } 

    // Checks if the next element exists 
    public boolean hasNext() { 
    } 

    // moves the cursor/iterator to next element 
    public T next() { 
    } 

    // Used to remove an element. Implement only if needed 
    public void remove() { 
        // Default throws UnsupportedOperationException. 
    } 
}
```

Code example is more or less taken from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-implementing-iterator-and-iterable-interface/).

Comment: Note that depending on the exact requirements, it's *possibly* not necessary to implement your own `Iterator`. Simply delegating to the `iterator()` method of the delegate list might be good enough.

Comment: @will25g: you already delegated `contains`, `delete` and `add`, why is `iterator` now problematic? ;-) `public Iterator<String> iterator() { return this.delegateList.iterator(); }` ought to do it.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks for the help man, I tried implementing it like that before - however When I tried to iterate through the LinkedLists in a for loop It gave me an error.

Comment: @will25g: add `implements Iterable<String>` to your class definition (in addition to that method) to make that work (that's what I meant by "implement `Iterable`" in my original comment).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thank you very much for your patience and will to help others. I really appreciate you.